# 8 puzzle solver in C

Tags: performance, c

The code works fine for inputs that have a solution. The goal board is

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8

I have tried to implement using the A* search algorithm. The code runs for 2 seconds or slightly more time which seems slow compared to the implementation in other languages. How do I optimize the code?
I have included two sample inputs within the code one of which requires longer time to run.

**Board**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
 //Sample input 3 0 1 3 4 2 5 7 8 6 
//Sample input 3 8 1 3 4 0 2 7 6 5 
int ** goal;
int N;

void allocate_mem(int ** * arr) {
  * arr = (int ** ) malloc(N * sizeof(int * ));
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    ( * arr)[i] = (int * ) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
}

void deallocate_mem(int ** * arr) {
  int i, N;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    free(( * arr)[i]);
  free( * arr);
}

void createTiles(int ** tiles, int ** arr) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
      tiles[i][j] = arr[i][j];
}

void createGoal(void) {
  int i, j;
  allocate_mem( & goal);
  int filler = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      if (i == N - 1 && j == N - 1)
        goal[i][j] = 0;
      else
        goal[i][j] = filler++;
    }
  }
}

void display(int ** t) {
  int i, j;
  printf("\n%d\n", N);
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      if (t[i][j] == 0) printf("  ");
      else
        printf("%d ", t[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int hamming(int ** tiles) {
  int count = 0, j, i;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      if (tiles[i][j] == 0) continue;
      if (tiles[i][j] != goal[i][j]) count++;
    }
  return count;
}

bool isGoal(int ** t) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
      if (t[i][j] != goal[i][j]) return false;
  return true;
}

bool equals(int ** p, int ** q) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
      if (p[i][j] != q[i][j]) return false;
  return true;
}

void swap(int ** surface, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
  int temp = surface[x1][y1];
  surface[x1][y1] = surface[x2][y2];
  surface[x2][y2] = temp;
}

void copy(int ** toRet, int ** origin) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
      toRet[i][j] = origin[i][j];
}

//finds twin of board by exchanging any two blocks
void boardTwin(int ** toRet) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N - 1; j++) {
      if (toRet[i][j] != 0 && toRet[i][j + 1] != 0) {
        swap(toRet, i, j, i, j + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}

typedef struct board_ {
  int ** data;
  // Lower values indicate higher priority 
  int cost;
  int level;
  struct board_ * parent;
}
board;

board * newBoard(int ** arr, board * parent, int level) {
  board * temp = (board * ) malloc(sizeof(board));
  allocate_mem( & (temp -> data));
  createTiles(temp -> data, arr);
  temp -> cost = hamming(arr);
  temp -> level = level;
  temp -> parent = parent;
  return temp;
}

typedef struct node {
  board * b;
  // Lower values indicate higher priority 
  int priority;
  struct node * next;
}
Node;

// Function to Create A New Node 
Node * newNode(board * brd) {
  Node * temp = (Node * ) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  temp -> b = brd;
  temp -> priority = brd -> cost + brd -> level;
  temp -> next = NULL;
  return temp;
}

// Return the value at head 
board * peek(Node ** head) {
  return ( * head) -> b;
}

// Removes the element with the 
// highest priority form the list 
void pop(Node ** head) {
  Node * temp = * head;
  ( * head) = ( * head) -> next;
  free(temp);
}

// Function to push according to priority 
void push(Node ** head, board * d) {
  Node * start = ( * head);
  // Create new Node 
  Node * temp = newNode(d);
  int p = d -> cost + d -> level;
  // Special Case: The head of list has lesser 
  // priority than new node. So insert new 
  // node before head node and change head node. 
  if (( * head) -> priority > p) {
    // Insert New Node before head 
    temp -> next = * head;
    ( * head) = temp;
  } else {

    // Traverse the list and find a 
    // position to insert new node 
    while (start -> next != NULL && start -> next -> priority < p) {
      start = start -> next;
    }

    // Either at the ends of the list 
    // or at required position 
    temp -> next = start -> next;
    start -> next = temp;
  }
}

// Function to check is list is empty 
int isEmpty(Node ** head) {
  return ( * head) == NULL;
}
void pushNeighbors(board * brd, Node * pq) {
  int i, j, stop = 0;
  int ** temp, ** t;
  allocate_mem( & temp);
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
      if (brd -> data[i][j] == 0) {
        stop = 1;
        break;
      }
    if (stop == 1) break;
  }
  if (i + 1 < N) {
    copy(temp, brd -> data);
    swap(temp, i + 1, j, i, j);
    board * dChild = newBoard(temp, brd, brd -> level + 1);
    if (pq == NULL) {
      pq = newNode(dChild);
    } else
      push( & pq, dChild);
  }
  if (j - 1 >= 0) {
    copy(temp, brd -> data);
    swap(temp, i, j - 1, i, j);
    board * lChild = newBoard(temp, brd, brd -> level + 1);
    if (pq == NULL) {
      pq = newNode(lChild);
    } else
      push( & pq, lChild);
  }
  if (i - 1 >= 0) {
    copy(temp, brd -> data);
    swap(temp, i - 1, j, i, j);
    board * uChild = newBoard(temp, brd, brd -> level + 1);
    if (pq == NULL) {
      pq = newNode(uChild);
    } else
      push( & pq, uChild);
  }

  if (j + 1 < N) {
    copy(temp, brd -> data);
    swap(temp, i, j + 1, i, j);
    board * rChild = newBoard(temp, brd, brd -> level + 1);
    if (pq == NULL) {
      pq = newNode(rChild);
    } else
      push( & pq, rChild);
  }

}

void printPath(board * root) {
  if (root == NULL) return;
  else printPath(root -> parent);
  display(root -> data);
}

void solve(int ** arr) {
  board * root = newBoard(arr, NULL, 0);
  Node * pq = newNode(root);
  int d = 0;
  while (!isEmpty( & pq)) {
    d++;
    board * peeked = peek( & pq);
    if (isGoal(peeked -> data)) {
      printf("\nPath");
      printPath(peeked);
      return;
    }
    //prints a dot to mind the user that code is running
    if (d >= 2500) {
      printf(". ");
      d = 0;
    }
    pushNeighbors(peeked, pq);
    pop( & pq);
  }
}

int main() {
  // Create a Priority Queue 
  int i, j, ** arr;
  printf("Enter input:");
  scanf("%d", & N);
  createGoal();
  arr = malloc(N * sizeof(int * )); // N is the number of the rows
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    arr[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int)); // N is the number of the columns
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      scanf("%d", & arr[i][j]);
    }
  solve(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

The code prints dots to notify that it's running.

Comment: One obvious major optimization is to get rid of your pointer look-up tables and use 2D arrays instead. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). As for general code review, your coding style is both inconsistent and hard to read, to the point where I can't be bothered reading the code. Always include empty lines between function bodies, to begin with.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this, not just performance problems. I would say this is not A*. For example, nothing prevents the same board from being generated and visited an infinite number of times.

Comment: @Lundin I had to generalise this later on for n-tile puzzle solver. So I have used 2D pointers instead of 2D arrays. I have also updated coding style and included empty lines.

Comment: @harold Same board might be generated but it's children will not be traversed. As the traversal takes place giving priority to lowest cost children, if same node is being generated again it's actual cost now will be higher than previous as number of moves increases and it will not be traversed. Also the code has never run infintely for any test case that has a solution.

Comment: A* is not supposed to run infinitely when there is no solution, it's supposed to run out of nodes to consider so it can detect that situation.

Comment: @harold Thank you. I am able to implement it faster by not generating the same board. Also, I have added a few lines that will detect the inputs with no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made two major changes for the code that made it faster to run.

1. I have avoided pushing parent of a particular node as its child. Code changes as follows

```
void pushNeighbors(board * brd, Node * pq) {
  int i, j, stop = 0;
  int ** temp, ** t;
  allocate_mem( & temp);
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
      if (brd -> data[i][j] == 0) {
        stop = 1;
        break;
      }
    if (stop == 1) break;
  }
  if (i + 1 < N) {
    copy(temp, brd -> data);
    swap(temp, i + 1, j, i, j);
    board * dChild = newBoard(temp, brd, brd -> level + 1);
    if (pq == NULL) {
      pq = newNode(dChild);
    } 
    else if(brd->parent == NULL)
      push( & pq, dChild);
      //Avoid pushing parent as a child again
    else if(!equals(brd->parent->data,dChild->data)) {
     push( & pq, dChild);   
    }
  }
  if (j - 1 >= 0) {
    copy(temp, brd -> data);
    swap(temp, i, j - 1, i, j);
    board * lChild = newBoard(temp, brd, brd -> level + 1);
    if (pq == NULL) {
      pq = newNode(lChild);
    } 
    else if(brd->parent == NULL)
      push( & pq, lChild);
      //Avoid pushing parent as a child again
    else if(!equals(brd->parent->data,lChild->data)) {
     push( & pq, lChild);   
    }  
  }
  if (i - 1 >= 0) {
    copy(temp, brd -> data);
    swap(temp, i - 1, j, i, j);
    board * uChild = newBoard(temp, brd, brd -> level + 1);
    if (pq == NULL) {
      pq = newNode(uChild);
    } 
    else if(brd->parent == NULL)
      push( & pq, uChild);
      //Avoid pushing parent as a child again
    else if(!equals(brd->parent->data,uChild->data)) {
     push( & pq, uChild);   
    }  
  }

  if (j + 1 < N) {
    copy(temp, brd -> data);
    swap(temp, i, j + 1, i, j);
    board * rChild = newBoard(temp, brd, brd -> level + 1);
    if (pq == NULL) {
      pq = newNode(rChild);
    }   
    else if(brd->parent == NULL)
      push( & pq, rChild);
      //Avoid pushing parent as a child again
    else if(!equals(brd->parent->data,rChild->data)) {
     push( & pq, rChild);   
    }  
  }
}
```

2. The code solves a twin board(two numbers from the actual board will be swapped). If the twin board is solved, no solution exists for the actually entered board.

```
void solve(int ** arr) {
  board * root = newBoard(arr, NULL, 0);
  Node * pq = newNode(root);
  //Creating a twin array to solve
   int **twinArr;
   int i;
   twinArr = malloc(N * sizeof(int * )); // N is the number of the rows
     for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
       twinArr[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int)); // N is the number of the columns
       copy(twinArr,arr);
       boardTwin(twinArr);
    board * rootTwin = newBoard(twinArr, NULL, 0);
    Node * pqTwin = newNode(rootTwin);
  //if twin is solved,no solution for main
  while (!isEmpty( & pq) || !isEmpty(&pqTwin)) {
    board * peeked = peek( & pq);
    board * peekedTwin = peek(& pqTwin);
    if (isGoal(peeked -> data)) {
      printf("\nPath");
      printPath(peeked);
      return;
    }
    //Checks if twin is solved
    if (isGoal(peekedTwin -> data)) {
      printf("\n No solution exists for entered board.");
      return;
    }
    pushNeighbors(peeked, pq);
    pop( & pq);
    //push peekedTwin neighbors
    pushNeighbors(peekedTwin, pqTwin);
    //pop minimum from twin queue
    pop( & pqTwin);
  }
}
```